# VS Code - Access only GitHub Pages

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

Totally newbie question on this, but I can't find other answers. I'm using VS Code on Ubuntu. After 'initializing' Git in VS Code, ALL of my local files in my home space show under Git in VS Code. I would like to limit this to my actual repository (one folder). I tried cd'ing to the folder I wish to be in git, in bash, and issuing 'git init'. Everything is still showing in VS Code. I have no desire to commit all of my practice work.

How do I restrict Git in VS Code to one folder?

Comment: When you init a git repository, git create a '.git' folder (which is hidden on Linux). Look if there is one that was created in your home folder. Perhaps you should delete this folder and do the 'git init' in the folder that you want to be your repository.

Comment: @Philippe, please add that an answer, that was it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you init a git repository, git create a '.git' folder (which is hidden on Linux). Look if there is one that was created in your home folder. Perhaps you should delete this folder and do the 'git init' in the folder that you want to be your repository.